# Inflate layout to view

Tags: android

I want to add view to window manager and this view must be my layout. But when I try to inflate layout and then add it I can only see one part of my layout(Button) and not the whole layout.Can somebody tell me what I do wrong?
My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.launcher_activity,null);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            params.x = 0;
            params.y = 100;

            windowManager.addView(v, params);
```

Comment: You're only seeing a Button because, I'd guess, that's the only visible thing in your layout.

Comment: @doug-stevenson Do you know how to make visible whole layout?

Comment: You **only** have a `Button` in your xml layout, what you want to see more?

Comment: @rami Ohhh, got it. But I want to see Button and background image

Comment: @S.Drumble3 Add a background to your `RelativeLayou` (`android:background="@drawable/your_image_drawable"`)

Comment: @rami Can I somehow show that white background font and my default action bar those I have in default layout?

Comment: @S.Drumble3 AFAIK you can't change your layout and action bar backgounds at the same time(with the same piece of code). You can use *ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable()* method, to set a background to your ActionBar.

Comment: @rami No, no, no.I want to have a window with default layout(just white background and action bar with name of my application).Can I do something like this?

Comment: @S.Drumble3 What do you mean by *"have a window"*? Why you don't use an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).

Comment: @rami Because I'm working on one project(freelance) and this project needs some feature of window and layout.